# How to get an App-only access token in React using Microsoft Graph Collector

Tags: reactjs, graph, microsoft-graph-api, access-token

Here, in the simplest form, we can get a delegated token, as we provide an account, but how would I get an app-only token?

```
import { useMsal } from '@azure/msal-react';

const myApp = () => {
     const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
     const request = {
            scopes: ["Scopes go here.."],
            account: accounts[0],
        };
        
        // Silently acquires an access token which is then attached to a request for Microsoft Graph data
        const response = await instance.acquireTokenSilent(request);
        console.log(response);

return (
        <>
            <h1>Title for app</h1>
            { /** Other info here */ }
        </>
    );
}

export default myApp;
```

I tried using @azure/msal-node but I run into installation issues. I can fixing by doing a rewire on the react-scripts and that's no problem but I still have an issue trying to get a simple app-only access token.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the `@azure/msal-browser` package instead of `@azure/msal-react` to obtain an app-only access token.

First you need to install the package;

```
npm install @azure/msal-browser
```

Then import the necessary module(s)

```
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';
```

Create an instance of `PublicClientApplication` with your client/application configuration

```
const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: "Your_Client_Id",
    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/Your_Tenant_Id",
  },
};

const pca = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
```

The acquire the app-only access token

```
const request = {
    scopes: ['Scopes go here...'],
};

const response = await pca.acquireTokenByClientCredential(request);
const accessToken = response.accessToken;
console.log(accessToken);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have tried using `acquireTokenByClientCredential` but I always get:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: pca.acquireTokenByClientCredential is not a function.

Comment: Just to confirm, are you importing `PublicClientApplication ` from  `@azure/msal-browser` and not `@azure/msal-react`?

Comment: Yes, I am using: 
   `import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';`
but pca, only has four functions to call, AcquireTokenByCode, AcquireTokenByPopup, AcquireTokenByRedirect, AcquireTokenBySilent. I do not see acquireTokenByClientCredential, and I when I use it I get an error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: pca.acquireTokenByClientCredential is not a function when calling it.